# handling state mutation on reactive programming project reactor

Tags: reactive-programming, project-reactor

i have a question regarding updating mutable state on reactive streams. I found the following code:

```
Mono<Transaction> closeTransaction(Long id) {
return transactionRepository.findById(1L)
.map(transaction -> transaction.setStatus("DONE")
.flatMap(transactionRepository::save);
}
```

Then, reading some books on functional and reactive programming, i have found that they suggest not mutating data state or doing some side effects activities on reactive primitives such as map. However i have found lot of reactive code written like above code. How should we handle state mutation on reactive frameworks? I'm woking on Java projects with project reactor and it is not clear which primitives should handle with mutable state and which shouldn't.

Thanks,
Jorge

Comment: As a solution i have used "wither" pattern in order to return a new object based on the older one that way we avoid mutating state on primitives. Also use of .handle() was very useful.